# External hard drive formatted with FAT won't mount on mac osx

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, external-disk, mount

I think I messed up a an external disk (Toshiba Canvio)  by incorrectly disconnecting it while it was being used and cannot get it to mount.
When I plug in the drive, the light blinks and is being read and read, then an error message comes up:
**“the disk you inserted was not readable by this computer”**

I was able to get it partially visible with Terminal diskutil usage as below, but don't know how to proceed to actually get access to the data?

I have tried the 2TB, FAT formatted Toshiba Canvio disk on an older 17" Macbook Pro with Yosemite as well as a new M1 Macbook Air.

Following info is copied from Terminal:

```
sh-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *512.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Data                    511.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 MOVIES                  2.0 TB     disk1s1
sh-3.2# diskutil info /dev/disk1
   Device Identifier:        disk1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1
   Part of Whole:            disk1
   Device / Media Name:      TOSHIBA External USB 3.0 Media

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      FDisk_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 USB
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               2.0 TB (2000398934016 Bytes) (exactly 3907029168 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported

sh-3.2# fdisk /dev/disk1
Disk: /dev/disk1    geometry: 243201/255/63 [3907029168 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 0B 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         2 - 3907029166] Win95 FAT-32
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
sh-3.2#
```

Comment: I'd be looking at something like [DiskDrill](https://www.cleverfiles.com). It may be possible to rescue the original formatting, but tha's above my paygrade ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin - Thank you so much. Problem solved with DiskDrill.  I had over 1500 movies on the disk and it saw each and every on and is currently backing up to another drive.
Now I just need some popcorn :-)

Comment: Glad you got it. TBH, I'd avoid FAT altogether as a disk format. Use ExFAT is you have to maintain multi-platform compatibility [or better still look into Win apps that enable HFS+ on Win], otherwise always use HFS+. It's journaled to protect against this type of fail.

Comment: I used a few of these hard drives to watch movies on my "dumb" TV via the USB port and it can only read FAT formatted hard drives  :-(

Comment: OK. You'll have to remember to Eject first then ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin After my initial excitement having DiskDrill "find" my hard drive and the entire contents, I think I have lost the entire disk. Countless emails, confusing statements, lack of information on their site....  got a full refund and am sitting with a completely messed up disk.

Comment: Then you're down to whatever other recovery tool you can find, or go to a data recovery company. I'd seriously rethink storing the only copy of anything on a non-journalled drive in future. Maybe set up a small 'porter' for the dumb TV.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the comment. I have already started making backups of everything on journaled, normal mac drives. grrrr